# What's the best way to programmatically detect the iPad 2's graphics hardware?

Tags: ipad, graphics, detection, hardware-acceleration, ipad-2

My app needs to run different code (larger textures) on iPad 2. How should I programmatically detect faster graphics hardware?

The code should be future-proof (i.e. it would detect faster graphics hardware on iPad 3 or any other future iOS devices that have it).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just go with the framerate, if it drops too much, go for the smaller textures, if it is way above 100 fps, take the bigger ones.